# compactMap on sequence() not lazy?

Tags: swift, lazy-sequences

Every once in a while I have to walk up the responder chain to reach an instance of a known class. (Just accept this for purposes of the question.) I've been doing this with a while loop, but it occurred to me that it would be cooler to use `sequence()`, which can express the responder chain itself neatly like this:

```
let chain = sequence(first: someView as UIResponder) {$0.next}
```

That's brilliant because so far we haven't actually done any walking; the sequence is lazy and the anonymous function won't be executed until we start asking for elements. To prove that, let me instrument that code with a print statement:

```
let chain = sequence(first: someView as UIResponder) {r in print(r); return r.next}
```

Okay, so let's say I'm looking for the first ViewController instance in the chain. I can find it like this:

```
if let vc = (chain.first {$0 is ViewController}) as? ViewController {
    print(vc)
}
```

The printout shows that laziness is maintained: we walked up the responder chain until we got to the ViewController and stopped. Perfect! Inside the curly braces, `vc` is typed as ViewController and we're off to the races.

It will not have escaped your attention, however, that that's ugly. I'm both testing and casting. Is there a way I can just cast without testing and still end up with a ViewController?

This is elegant and it works fine:

```
for case let vc as ViewController in chain {
    print(vc)
    break
}
```

That's lovely and laziness is maintained — but I have to remember to say `break` at the end, which sort of ruins everything.

Okay, so I was really hopeful when I thought of this:

```
if let vc = (chain.compactMap{ $0 as? ViewController }.first) {
    print(vc)
}
```

It works in the sense that it compiles and gets the right answer and looks nice, but I've *lost laziness*. The entire `chain` is being traversed. Does `compactMap` lose laziness? Is there a way to get it back? (Or is there some other elegant way that has completely escaped me?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is not `compactMap`, per se. There are two issues:

1. If you want the sequence to call `compactMap` lazily, you need to use [`lazy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unfoldsequence/2012466-lazy).
2. It would appear that `first` is preventing the lazy behavior. If you use `first(where:)`, though, you do enjoy the lazy behavior.

Thus, while somewhat inelegant, the following achieves what you’re looking for:

```
if let vc = (chain.lazy.compactMap { $0 as? ViewController }.first { _ in true } ) {
    ...
}
```

Or, as you say, you can implement `first` (or `lazyFirst`) on `Sequence`:

```
extension Sequence {
    var first: Element? {
        return first { _ in true }
    }
}
```

And then this more simplified rendition now is still lazy:

```
if let vc = chain.lazy.compactMap({ $0 as? ViewController }).first {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I added a comment to https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5754, I believe it’s related.