# Why lazy.compactMap.first maps 'first' element twice?

Tags: swift

I'm testing compactMap for lazy array to find first element and map it in a few lines of code.

```
"abc5def".lazy
  .compactMap {
    print($0)
    return Int(String($0))
}.first as Int?
```

Prints

```
a
b
c
5
5
```

Why last element being mapped twice. How to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782134/compactmap-on-sequence-not-lazy

Comment: @MartinR Is this because `first` is a property while `first(where:)` is a method?

Comment: Also related (if not a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940243/why-does-filter-s-predicate-get-called-so-many-times-when-evaluating-it-lazi.

Comment: Thanks! `.first(where: { _ in true })` works better. I think i need to check swift's source code to find why this happend. 
@JoakimDanielson `.first` has to be a getter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compactMap on sequence() not lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782134/compactmap-on-sequence-not-lazy)

Comment: What is interesting – if you put chain `lazy.compactMap(...).first(where: { _ in true })` in a separate Collection's extension method – it stops working.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR** The `compactMap` call returns a chain of lazy sequences `LazyMapSequence<LazyFilterSequence<LazyMapSequence<...`, this, combined with the fact that `first` needs to compute both the start index, as well as the element at that start index, results in the transform closure being called twice:

1. when `startIndex` is computed
2. when retrieving the element at the start index

---

[This](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c1554f6d7a953d6c00fb6d97ce984418e27fc137/stdlib/public/core/FlatMap.swift#L42) is the current implementation of `compactMap` over  `LazySequenceProtocol` (a protocol that all lazy sequences conform to):

```swift
public func compactMap<ElementOfResult>(
    _ transform: @escaping (Elements.Element) -> ElementOfResult?
  ) -> LazyMapSequence<
    LazyFilterSequence<
      LazyMapSequence<Elements, ElementOfResult?>>,
    ElementOfResult
  > {
    return self.map(transform).filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
}
```

This makes your `"abc5def".lazy.compactMap { ... }` to be of type `LazyMapSequence<LazyFilterSequence<LazyMapSequence<String, Optional<Int>>>, Int>`.

Secondly, you're asking about the `first` element from the lazy sequence. This resolves to the [default implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c1554f6d7a953d6c00fb6d97ce984418e27fc137/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1101) of `first` over the `Collection` protocol (all lazy sequences get automatic conformance to `Collection` if their base sequence is also a collection):

```swift
public var first: Element? {
    let start = startIndex
    if start != endIndex { return self[start] }
    else { return nil }
}
```

This means that `first` has to retrieve two pieces of information:

1. the start index
2. the value at the start index (the subscript part)

Now, it's the `startIndex` computation that causes the duplicate evaluation, due to [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/c1554f6d7a953d6c00fb6d97ce984418e27fc137/stdlib/public/core/Filter.swift#L140) implementation over `LazyFilterSequence`:

```swift
public var startIndex: Index {
    var index = _base.startIndex
    while index != _base.endIndex && !_predicate(_base[index]) {
      _base.formIndex(after: &index)
    }
    return index
}
```

The `subscript` implementation over `LazyMapSequence` is a standard one:

```swift
public subscript(position: Base.Index) -> Element {
    return _transform(_base[position])
}
```

, however, as you can see, the transform is called again, resulting in the second print you see.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to use the `first` function in place of the computed property.

Example:

```
"abc5def".lazy.compactMap { Int(String($0)) }.first { _ in true }
```